# Next.js build Vercel error (Digest: 251669207)

Tags: next.js, vercel

After building in Vercel, I got a white screen with message:

> Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).Digest: 251669207

And the console says:

> Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.

I had all .env files and tried to reinstall, but I still got this error.

And Vercel Logs:

```
ClientError: GraphQL Error (Code: 503): {"response":{"error":"config worker not available","status":503,"headers":{}},"request":{"query":"\n  query getProjects($category: String, $endcursor: String) {\n    projectSearch(first: 8, after: $endcursor, filter: {category: {eq: $category}}) {\n      pageInfo {\n        hasNextPage\n        hasPreviousPage\n        startCursor\n        endCursor\n      }\n      edges {\n        node {\n          title\n          githubUrl\n          description\n          liveSiteUrl\n          id\n          image\n          category\n          createdBy {\n            id\n            email\n            name\n            avatarUrl\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n","variables":{}}}
    at makeRequest (/var/task/node_modules/graphql-request/build/cjs/index.js:310:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async makeGraphQLRequest (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/147.js:191:16)
    at async Home (/var/task/.next/server/app/page.js:644:18) {
  response: {
    error: 'config worker not available',
    status: 503,
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] }
  },
  request: {
    query: '\n' +
      '  query getProjects($category: String, $endcursor: String) {\n' +
      '    projectSearch(first: 8, after: $endcursor, filter: {category: {eq: $category}}) {\n' +
      '      pageInfo {\n' +
      '        hasNextPage\n' +
      '        hasPreviousPage\n' +
      '        startCursor\n' +
      '        endCursor\n' +
      '      }\n' +
      '      edges {\n' +
      '        node {\n' +
      '          title\n' +
      '          githubUrl\n' +
      '          description\n' +
      '          liveSiteUrl\n' +
      '          id\n' +
      '          image\n' +
      '          category\n' +
      '          createdBy {\n' +
      '            id\n' +
      '            email\n' +
      '            name\n' +
      '            avatarUrl\n' +
      '          }\n' +
      '        }\n' +
      '      }\n' +
      '    }\n' +
      '  }\n',
    variables: { category: undefined, endcursor: undefined }
  }
}
[Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] {
  digest: '251669207'
}
```

Comment: Does it error if you build it locally?

Comment: @Matt Nope its build ok

Comment: Does `yarn next lint` or `npm run next lint` surface anything?

Comment: Go to Vercel, Logs tab. Post here your error

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error in my application and it turns out my `API_URL` environment variable in Vercel was incorrect.  Even after I changed it and redeployed, I was still getting the error.  I had to go to my `project settings`, select `Data Cache` and click the red `Purge Everything` button.  Once I did that I had to again redeploy and my application loaded successfully.  Hopefully this helps someone